# Express returning error 500, no stack trace

Tags: node.js, express

I'm sending request to my express based server, and getting 500 but without a stack trace. Other errors printed directly to console.

Response: 
`PUT /test 500 57207.231 ms - 1201`

1. I tried to catch those errors in error handling, but still no luck.

   ```
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

     _logger.log('500 ERROR', err.message);

     res.status(err.status || 500);
     res.render('error', {
       message: err.message,
       error: {}
     });
   });
   ```
2. I've set requestTimeut to 0 in the relevant request.

   ```
   router.put('/', middlewares.isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
      ....
      req.setTimeout(0);
      ....
   });
   ```

How can i pinpoint the error?

Comment: Does the error handler get triggered at all?

Comment: It does not, that's why i'm failing to understand where to debug.